# Transparent loading view while fetching data from web service objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

could someone please refer me to a good tutorial on creating a transparent loading view with a UIActivityIndicator or UIProgressIndicator while data is being fetch to UITableView from a web service. I want the loading view to cover the whole screen up to the navigationBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, you are looking for something like [MBProgressHud](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD). It's an opensource project, which looks like the progresshud you sometimes see in iOS. I used it afew times and iht's really great. With this approach you don't have to write your own class to achieve this. ;-)

Sandro Meier

Comment: I agree. Design and appearance is easily modified if defaults are not suited for his app. Doing the whole thing from scratch looks like big waste of time when MBProgressHud is open source.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color of the elements on your ui to [`UIColor clearcolor]` to achive the transparency.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking of something like a presentModalView that is transparent and holds a UIActivityIndicator or UIProgressBar. When the ViewController holding the UITableView gets pushed on the navigation stack the loading view will be display over.

Comment: I remember seeing a tutorial on somebody doing this after a login screen but can´t find it.

Comment: You can present any view as modal or add as subview by making the elements transparent. Either i am not getting your doubt correctly or you are not clear in what you want.

Comment: Well you can put a activity indicator on top of any view and when loading is completed remove it and stop animating.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know ... if you present a modalview... the view underneath unloads. I tried it many times with modalViews having alpha = 0,5 or something.